# assign empty pointer to multiple variables

Tags: python

for value assignment to multiple variables, i tried `a=b=c=3`, it works!

however, for assigning empty pointers to multiple variable, `a=b=c=[]` would like assign the same pointer addr to multiple variables, that is not i desire....

i want to init the variables with empty pointers that would later point to diff data chunks.

for now i did it like:

```
a=[]
b=[]
c=[]
```

quite a long list. could i do it a better and pythonic way?

Comment: `a, b, c = [], [], []`?

Comment: Python doesn't have 'pointers'.

Comment: Have you had a look at numpy?

Comment: @user3 It is the same; it assigns the same one as well.

Comment: If not called it pointer? What should I call it? I suppose the so-called "reference" is exactly same as pointer in c, not true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a, b, c = [ [] for i in range(3) ]
```